# Como ler um arquivo XML do servidor

Tags: java, xml, socket

To criando uma aplicação java desktop que acessa a internet e le um arquivo xml. Bem, esse é o proprosito inicial. Estou utilizando a classe Socket para fazer a comunicação entre o servidor e a aplicação. Mas agora nao sei como fazer para ler o xml. 
Mudei meu codigo, no while eu pretendo gravar o XML. Ainda procurando como.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        //conectando
        URL url = new URL("http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //pegando informações
        BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter("D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\arquivo.txt");
        PrintWriter gravArq = new PrintWriter(arquivo);

        while ((line = leitor.readLine()) != null)
        {
            gravArq = gravArq.printf(line);
        }
        leitor.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();


    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) { System.out.println("Erro ao criar url: formato invalido"); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendo a URL do arquivo XML, por exemplo `www.seusite.com.br/arquivo.xml` você pode usar a API SAX.

**Um exemplo (não testado):**

```
String url = "http://www.seusite.com.br/arquivo.xml";
XMLReader myReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
myReader.setContentHandler(handler);
myReader.parse(new InputSource(new URL(url).openStream()));
```

Para mais informações leia o manual do SAX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou ler a documentação e os arquivos que tenho sobre SAX e Dom no caminho pra casa. VLW mesmo